# Is there a way to estimate multinomial proportions with confidence intervals using R survey package?

Tags: r, statistics, multinomial, proportions

I have a survey data, with categorical variables. I would like to compute the proportion for each responses in Q1, as well as generating the confidence interval or uncertainty around the estimate. Is that doable? The dataset already has sample weight generated. I am using R survey package but can't seem to get my head around it. An example table below
Thank you

| ID | Personweight | Q1 | Q2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11 | 1.3 | 1 | 4 |
| 13 | 1.5 | 3 | 3 |
| 16 | 1.3 | 4 | 2 |
| 18 | 1.3 | 2 | 3 |
| 19 | 1.6 | 1 | 1 |

## Create a survey design object

survey_design <- svydesign(ids = ~1, data = xxx, weights = ~Personweight)

## Calculate the multinomial proportions

proportions <- svyciprop(~Q1, survey_design)

#error seems to suggest that this function doesn't work for non-binary variable.

Comment: The ```svyciprop``` documentation explicitly says that the argument "formula" is for a "[m]odel formula specifying a single binary variable." So, I'm not sure how to make ```svyciprop```, with it's impressive suite of methods for estimating SEs, work for multinomial proportions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're happy with the ordinary +/- 1.96 standard error confidence intervals, you can just use `svymean` and `confint`.

Using one of the built-in examples:

```
> svymean(~stype, dclus2)
          mean     SE
stypeE 0.68118 0.0556
stypeH 0.13432 0.0567
stypeM 0.18450 0.0222
> confint(svymean(~stype, dclus2))
            2.5 %    97.5 %
stypeE 0.57212715 0.7902345
stypeH 0.02312234 0.2455123
stypeM 0.14094122 0.2280625
```

If you want one of the other methods, you need to do some data wrangling. You could use `svyciprop` on binary indicators

```
> svyciprop(~I(stype=="E"),dclus2,method="xlogit")
                       2.5% 97.5%
I(stype == "E") 0.681 0.560 0.782
```

or you could transform using `svycontrast`, use `confint`, and then transform back, which is what actually happens in `svyciprop`

```
> m<-svymean(~stype, dclus2)
> l<-svycontrast(m, quote(log(stypeE/(1-stypeE))))
> c<-confint(l,df=degf(dclus2))
> exp(c)/(1+exp(c))
             2.5 %   97.5 %
contrast 0.5599558 0.782011
```

The only issue now is how to write the loop that does this for all levels. Perhaps something like

```
> f<-function(level) eval(bquote(
       svyciprop(~I(stype==.(level)),dclus2,method="xlogit")
     ))
> lapply(c("E","M","H"),f)
[[1]]
                       2.5% 97.5%
I(stype == "E") 0.681 0.560 0.782

[[2]]
                       2.5% 97.5%
I(stype == "M") 0.185 0.144 0.234

[[3]]
                         2.5%  97.5%
I(stype == "H") 0.1343 0.0547 0.2939
```

Comment: For proportions near 0 or 1, ```confint``` often produces confidence interval estimates out of bounds (i.e., below 0 or above 1). I'm trying to figure out how to use ```svyciprop```, which has different options for estimating the CIs (including "logit", "xlogit", and "beta"). But ```svyciprop``` requires a single, binary variable, so I'm not sure how to put the square peg of multinomial variables into the round hole of ```svyciprop```. Anyone out there know? Perhaps Prof. @Thomas Lumley, who invented the marvelous ```survey``` package?

Comment: edited to give more information: there isn't a magic solution

Comment: Thanks, @Thomas Lumley! I feared there wasn't a magic solution; oh, well, a little more work for me. Any possibility of implementing the code you wrote above for ```svyciprop``` with ```svymean```, ```svytable```, or the other functions?

Comment: Eh. The problem is that `svymean` is very much not for this, and it doesn't know if the variables it is analysing are supposed to be multinomial. It would make more sense for `svyciprop` to automate this

Comment: I've found all this out through trial and error--lots of it! It's a wonderful package; congratulations and many thanks. It would make sense for ```svyciprop``` to automate this (and the risk of coming off as an ingrate). Since it doesn't, though, I'm trying to find a workaround, extending the ones you've posted above, for getting confidence intervals around cell proportions of a two-way table in which both variables are categorical. I'll post an answer as soon as I find it! Again, thanks, Prof. @Thomas Lumley.

Comment: I've been wracking my brains for several days now, but I can't figure out how to get CIs around cell or row proportions. I think I'll post a new question with the code I have, but for now, what if "stype" (percentage of schools that are elementary, middle, or high schools) were cross-classified with, say, "dname" (district name), which would give us the percentage of each type of school for each school district, Prof @Thomas Lumley?

Comment: New question is here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77755536/how-can-i-get-cis-around-row-proportions-in-the-survey-package