# How can I get CIs around row proportions in the "survey" package?

Tags: r, survey, confidence-interval

*[Edited 1/4 to specify that CIs should be bounded by 0 and 1]*

### The Goal

I have survey data using a complex survey design (from the California Health Interview Survey, CHIS) and am trying to use the `survey` package to obtain estimates of proportions for each of four sexual orientation categories (straight, gay/lesbian, bisexual, and other) in all 58 counties in California using the `survey` package.

So, for example, in Alameda County, 92% of its residents might be straight; 3.5%, gay or lesbian; 3.5%, bisexual; and 1%, "other." The goal is to get a confidence interval around each of those proportions (e.g., 92% [91.3%, 92.7%]), for all counties.

**Note: Since we're dealing with probabilities, the confidence limits should neither exceed 1 nor fall below 0.**

### Reprex

Here's a reproducible example:

```
#Packages
require(survey)
require(dplyr)
require(tidyverse)

#Create data frame
# Set the number of trials and the probabilities for each outcome
set.seed(130)
probs <- c(.94, .03, .02, .01)
n <- 2000

sogi <- data.frame(t(rmultinom(n, 1, prob = probs)))
names(sogi) <- c("straight","gay","bisexual","other")
df_sogi <- sogi %>% mutate(sexual_orientation = 
                             as.factor(case_when(
                               straight %in% 1 ~ 0,
                               gay %in% 1 ~ 1,
                               bisexual %in% 1 ~ 2,
                               other %in% 1 ~ 3))) %>%
  mutate(pw = runif(n, 0.2, 3.5)) %>%
  mutate(county = as.factor(rep(LETTERS[1:10], each = n/length(LETTERS[1:10])))) %>%
  mutate(ind = row_number()) %>%
  select(ind, county, sexual_orientation, pw) 

#Examine raw frequencies
table(df_sogi$county, df_sogi$sexual_orientation)

#Make survey design and survey design replicate objects
df_svy_z1 <- svydesign(id=~ind, data = df_sogi, weights = ~pw, strata = ~county)
```

### Solution Attempt #1

Here's the closest I've gotten, which uses `svyglm`:

```
#w/ svyglm
s <- svyglm(sexual_orientation == 0 ~ county, design = df_svy_z1, family="quasibinomial")
a <- predict(s, newdata=df_sogi, type="link", se.fit=TRUE)
b <- unique(confint(a))
exp(b)/(1+exp(b))

> exp(b)/(1+exp(b))
         2.5 %    97.5 %
1    0.8525092 0.9479540
201  0.8641069 0.9584830
401  0.8766525 0.9607483
601  0.8552640 0.9504926
801  0.8743262 0.9592262
1001 0.9143716 0.9814168
1201 0.8587895 0.9514747
1401 0.9316797 0.9862013
1601 0.8660052 0.9532556
1801 0.8633378 0.9532417
```

I would then write a function that loops over each of the values of the `sexual_orientation` variable {0, 1, 2, 3}--not an easy task, given that (for me, anyway) invoking named objects and their values is devilishly difficult in `survey` (or maybe just R generally).

More vexingly yet, I'm not at all sure that the confidence intervals obtained by this method are correct; they seem way too wide.

### Solution Attempt #2

An alternative strategy could use `svymean`:

```
s <- svymean(~interaction(sexual_orientation, county), design=df_svy_z1)
x <- svycontrast(s, quote(log(`interaction(sexual_orientation, county)0.A` /
                                  (1-`interaction(sexual_orientation, county)0.A`))))
y <- confint(x)
z <- 1/(1+exp(-y))
```

The two big problems here are that (1) the proportions are cell proportions, not row proportions--i.e., frequencies expressed as a proportion of the entire sample, not of the sample within a given county--and (2) looping over the named objects involves replacing the expression `` quote(log(`interaction(sexual_orientation, county)0.A`/(1-`interaction(sexual_orientation, county)0.A`)))) `` with a more general expression for each of the 40 named values in the object `s`, which I haven't figured out how to do yet.

### Similar, but Different, Post

My question is similar to this one:
[Is there a way to estimate multinomial proportions with confidence intervals using R survey package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76320119/is-there-a-way-to-estimate-multinomial-proportions-with-confidence-intervals-usi/76336866?noredirect=1#comment136936054_76336866)

But the answers there, graciously provided by Prof. @Thomas Lumley, only deal with marginal probabilities--that is, with proportions of straight, gay/lesbian, etc., individuals for the *entire state*, and not for each county.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There may be a more elegant solution, but you can try using `svyby` here to first get the means by county:

```
library(survey)

svmeans <- svyby(~ sexual_orientation, 
                 design = df_svy_z1, 
                 by = ~ county, 
                 FUN = svymean)

#   county sexual_orientation0 sexual_orientation1 sexual_orientation2 sexual_orientation3 se.sexual_orientation0 se.sexual_orientation1
# A      A           0.9398657          0.02097910         0.023836687         0.015318555             0.01794317             0.01066598
# B      B           0.9433422          0.02165069         0.033570977         0.001436098             0.01845545             0.01154185
# C      C           0.9327511          0.03279607         0.022840837         0.011612004             0.01966055             0.01504690
# ....
```

Then if you are ok with a standard Wald CI using the standard error, wrap that in `confint()`

```
svCIs <- confint(svmeans)

#                               2.5 %      97.5 %
# A:sexual_orientation0  9.046977e-01 0.975033618
# B:sexual_orientation0  9.071702e-01 0.979514244
# C:sexual_orientation0  8.942171e-01 0.971285064
# D:sexual_orientation0  8.881002e-01 0.969468334
# ....
```

The returned objects are a bit unwieldy, so to make sense of it all, you can pretty up the objects and merge them:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

svmeans_long <- pivot_longer(svmeans[,-grep("se\\.", names(svmeans))], -county, 
                             names_to = "sexual_orientation",
                             values_to = "mean")

svCIs_long <- data.frame(svCIs) %>%
  tibble::rownames_to_column() %>%
  separate_wider_delim(rowname, delim = ":", 
                       names = c("county", "sexual_orientation"))

final_data <- left_join(svmeans_long, svCIs_long)

#   county sexual_orientation     mean     X2.5.. X97.5..
#   <chr>  <chr>                 <dbl>      <dbl>   <dbl>
# 1 A      sexual_orientation0 0.940    0.905     0.975  
# 2 A      sexual_orientation1 0.0210   0.0000742 0.0419 
# 3 A      sexual_orientation2 0.0238   0.00390   0.0438 
# 4 A      sexual_orientation3 0.0153  -0.00590   0.0365 
# 5 B      sexual_orientation0 0.943    0.907     0.980  
# ....
```

---

**EDIT**

Based on the comments/edit, if the proportions are close to 0 or 1, the Wald CI may not be appropriate. In this case you can still use `svyby` but use `svyciprop` for each level of `sexual_orientation`. The function `svyciprop` allows for various types of confidence intervals to be calculated.

Here is an example looping through all the levels of `sexual_orientation` and using the `xlogit` CI option):

```
svList <- list()

for(xx in sort(unique(df_sogi$sexual_orientation))){
  svList[[xx]]  <- svyby(~ I(sexual_orientation == xx),
        design = df_svy_z1,
        by = ~ county,
        FUN = svyciprop,
        vartype = "ci",
        method = "xlogit") # or "beta" or "logit" or "likelihood", etc see `?svyciprop`
  # tweak the output for convenience
  svList[[xx]]$sexual_orientation <- xx
  names(svList[[xx]])[2] <- "mean"
}

# combine it all together and order according to county
do.call(rbind, svList)[order(do.call(rbind, svList)$county),]

#     county        mean         ci_l       ci_u sexual_orientation
# 0.A      A 0.911193691 0.8520671385 0.94812694                  0
# 1.A      A 0.036149402 0.0149796639 0.08466537                  1
# 2.A      A 0.042363554 0.0196451241 0.08897020                  2
# 3.A      A 0.010293353 0.0018801543 0.05430515                  3
# 0.B      B 0.923758035 0.8636429959 0.95863968                  0
# 1.B      B 0.036042649 0.0141337843 0.08885182                  1
# 2.B      B 0.038706656 0.0164219903 0.08851038                  2
# 3.B      B 0.001492660 0.0002056946 0.01074521                  3
# ....
```

Comment: Thanks, @jpsmith! I had already tried `svyby` followed by `confint`. Unfortunately, if you look at the confidence intervals returned, a number of the values are below 0. I need confidence intervals bounded by 0 and 1. I'll edit the question to emphasize this and upvote your solution if you can address this problem.

Comment: @DavidCrow gotcha - see edit and let me know if that gives you what you want? Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to write some functions, since `svyby` can take user-written functions.  Here's a minimal version:

```
one_level<-function(level, design)  eval(bquote(attr(svyciprop(~I(sexual_orientation==.(level)), design, method="xlogit"),"ci")))
one_county<-function(formula, design,...) do.call(c, lapply(0:3, one_level, design=design))
svyby(~sexual_orientation, ~county, one_county, design=df_svy_z1, keep.var=FALSE)
```

`one_county` has a `formula` argument because that's what `svyby` expects, but it ignores it because `~sexual_orientation` is hard-coded in `one_level`. The levels are also hard-coded into `one_county`.  The key trick is to extract the confidence interval as the return value rather than as a variance-related attribute -- the call to `attr(, "ci")`

The names are also not ideal: the CIs go across, so (.852, .948) is the interval for the first level in county A.

```
  county statistic.2.5% statistic.97.5% statistic.2.5% statistic.97.5% statistic.2.5%
A      A          0.852           0.948        0.01498          0.0847       0.019645
B      B          0.864           0.959        0.01413          0.0889       0.016422
C      C          0.876           0.961        0.00979          0.0664       0.015733
D      D          0.855           0.951        0.02639          0.1050       0.002166
E      E          0.874           0.959        0.02292          0.0928       0.005346
F      F          0.914           0.982        0.01199          0.0683       0.002201
G      G          0.858           0.952        0.01176          0.0662       0.017503
H      H          0.931           0.986        0.00671          0.0449       0.000817
I      I          0.866           0.953        0.02963          0.1125       0.004708
J      J          0.863           0.953        0.01644          0.0785       0.015777
  statistic.97.5% statistic.2.5% statistic.97.5%
A          0.0890       0.001880          0.0543
B          0.0885       0.000206          0.0107
C          0.0836       0.001518          0.0397
D          0.0557       0.006729          0.0651
E          0.0571       0.001121          0.0559
F          0.0572            NaN             NaN
G          0.0907       0.003697          0.0603
H          0.0414       0.001056          0.0529
I          0.0355       0.002012          0.0355
J          0.0858       0.001009          0.0506
```

The

Comment: Many thanks, Prof. @Thomas Lumley. It's not working straight out of the box (the error I'm getting is `Error in as.data.frame.default(x[[i]], optional = TRUE) : cannot coerce class ‘"function"’ to a data.frame`), but I'll tinker with it. I'm very grateful for your help on this question and others I've posted for `survey`.

Comment: Ok, that's strange. I just checked and it does work for me by cut and paste from above (I made one change to your code: `require(rlang)` instead of `require(tidyverse)` to get the pipe)