# Why is this looping function returning one element of both for loop and lapply list?

Tags: r, for-loop, regression, lapply, survey

### The Goal

I'm trying to estimate proportions and CIs for each of four levels of my variable `sexual_orientation` (straight, gay/lesbian, bisexual, other) for each county in California using the `survey` package, to account for complex survey design. What I expect to get is this (thanks to @jpsmith for looping code using `svyby`):

```
    county        mean         ci_l       ci_u sex_orient
0.A      A 0.911193691 0.8520671385 0.94812694          0
1.A      A 0.036149402 0.0149796639 0.08466537          1
2.A      A 0.042363554 0.0196451241 0.08897020          2
3.A      A 0.010293353 0.0018801543 0.05430515          3
0.B      B 0.923758035 0.8636429959 0.95863968          0
1.B      B 0.036042649 0.0141337843 0.08885182          1
2.B      B 0.038706656 0.0164219903 0.08851038          2
3.B      B 0.001492660 0.0002056946 0.01074521          3
```

### The Problem

When I try to wrap the loop code in a function, though, I get only the proportions for the last level ("other") of my `sexual_orientation` variable:

```
0.A      A 0.010293353 0.0018801543 0.05430515                  0
1.A      A 0.010293353 0.0018801543 0.05430515                  1
2.A      A 0.010293353 0.0018801543 0.05430515                  2
3.A      A 0.010293353 0.0018801543 0.05430515                  3
0.B      B 0.001492660 0.0002056946 0.01074521                  0
1.B      B 0.001492660 0.0002056946 0.01074521                  1
2.B      B 0.001492660 0.0002056946 0.01074521                  2
3.B      B 0.001492660 0.0002056946 0.01074521                  3
```

### Reprex

```
library(survey)
library(dplyr)

#Create df
# Set the number of trials and the probabilities for each outcome
set.seed(130)
probs <- c(.94, .03, .02, .01)
n <- 2000

sogi <- data.frame(t(rmultinom(n, 1, prob = probs)))
names(sogi) <- c("straight","gay","bisexual","other")
df_sogi <- sogi %>% mutate(sexual_orientation =
                             as.factor(case_when(
                               straight %in% 1 ~ 0,
                               gay %in% 1 ~ 1,
                               bisexual %in% 1 ~ 2,
                               other %in% 1 ~ 3))) %>%
  mutate(pw = runif(n, 0.2, 3.5)) %>%
  mutate(county = as.factor(rep(LETTERS[1:10], each = n/length(LETTERS[1:10])))) %>%
  mutate(ind = row_number()) %>%
  select(ind, county, sexual_orientation, pw)

table(df_sogi$county, df_sogi$sexual_orientation)

#Make survey design and survey design replicate objects
df_svy_z1 <- svydesign(id=~ind, data = df_sogi, weights = ~pw, strata = ~county)
```

### Attempt 1

```
###In function taking df arg
get_table <- function(df) {
  svCounty <- list()
  for(i in sort(unique(df[ , "sexual_orientation"]))) {
    svCounty[[i]]  <- svyby(~ I(sexual_orientation == i),
                           design = df_svy_z1,
                           by = ~ county,
                           FUN = svyciprop,
                           vartype = "ci",
                           method = "xlogit") 
    
    svCounty[[i]]$sexual_orientation <- i
    names(svCounty[[i]])[2] <- "mean"
  }
  return(svCounty)
}

do.call(rbind, get_table(df_sogi))[order(do.call(rbind, get_table(df_sogi))$county), ]
```

### Attempt 2

```
###In function looping through values of sexual_orientation
svCounty <- list()
get_table <- function(i) {
  svCounty[[i]] <- svyby(~ I(sexual_orientation == i),
                         design = df_svy_z1,
                         by = ~ county,
                         FUN = svyciprop,
                         vartype = "ci",
                         method = "xlogit")
  svCounty[[i]]$sex_orient <- i
  names(svCounty[[i]])[2] <- "mean"
  
  svCounty[[i]]
}

rbindlist(lapply(sort(unique(df_sogi$sexual_orientation)), get_table))
```

How can I make these functions work, please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `sprintf` and `as.formula`. Since we have a factor variable we can exploit `levels`. I'd rather use the `"survey.design"` instead of the raw data to avoid confusion.

```
> library(survey)
> 
> lapply(levels(df_svy_z1$variables$sexual_orientation), \(x) {
+   fo <- sprintf('~ I(sexual_orientation == %s)', x) |> as.formula()
+   fit <- svyby(formula=fo, design=df_svy_z1, by=~county, 
+         FUN=svyciprop, vartype="ci", method="xlogit")
+   names(fit)[2] <- 'mean'
+   fit$sexual_orientation <- x
+   fit
+ }) |> do.call(what='rbind')
   county        mean         ci_l       ci_u sexual_orientation
A       A 0.911193691 0.8520671385 0.94812694                  0
B       B 0.923758035 0.8636429959 0.95863968                  0
C       C 0.929524740 0.8762428563 0.96089073                  0
D       D 0.914172405 0.8548171915 0.95066197                  0
E       E 0.927501303 0.8739160975 0.95937173                  0
F       F 0.959591984 0.9139878698 0.98150581                  0
G       G 0.916107681 0.8583546261 0.95163978                  0
H       H 0.968962680 0.9313564497 0.98627013                  0
I       I 0.919874178 0.8655967205 0.95341196                  0
J       J 0.919018480 0.8629143921 0.95340118                  0
A1      A 0.036149402 0.0149796639 0.08466537                  1
B1      B 0.036042649 0.0141337843 0.08885182                  1
C1      C 0.025837059 0.0097931213 0.06640293                  1
D1      D 0.053382252 0.0263936541 0.10499180                  1
E1      E 0.046687261 0.0229193724 0.09276293                  1
F1      F 0.028968138 0.0119900253 0.06832504                  1
G1      G 0.028234286 0.0117621310 0.06622873                  1
H1      H 0.017505999 0.0067078219 0.04490118                  1
I1      I 0.058574701 0.0296281887 0.11252238                  1
J1      J 0.036362103 0.0164375895 0.07850995                  1
A2      A 0.042363554 0.0196451241 0.08897020                  2
B2      B 0.038706656 0.0164219903 0.08851038                  2
C2      C 0.036774521 0.0157330277 0.08356782                  2
D2      D 0.011188560 0.0021662472 0.05569108                  2
E2      E 0.017724015 0.0053455758 0.05712038                  2
F2      F 0.011439877 0.0022008972 0.05723769                  2
G2      G 0.040455477 0.0175027776 0.09072823                  2
H2      H 0.005907451 0.0008172062 0.04139059                  2
I2      I 0.013016323 0.0047080705 0.03546360                  2
J2      J 0.037334343 0.0157769021 0.08578046                  2
A3      A 0.010293353 0.0018801543 0.05430515                  3
B3      B 0.001492660 0.0002056946 0.01074521                  3
C3      C 0.007863680 0.0015179030 0.03968435                  3
D3      D 0.021256783 0.0067288906 0.06509525                  3
E3      E 0.008087422 0.0011207690 0.05593360                  3
F3      F 0.000000000          NaN        NaN                  3
G3      G 0.015202557 0.0036968435 0.06034853                  3
H3      H 0.007623870 0.0010562198 0.05286832                  3
I3      I 0.008534798 0.0020115015 0.03546143                  3
J3      J 0.007285074 0.0010090080 0.05062042                  3
```

You can wrap this in a function like so:

```
get_table <- \(dsg) {
  lapply(levels(dsg$variables$sexual_orientation), \(x) {
    fo <- sprintf('~ I(sexual_orientation == %s)', x) |> as.formula()
    fit <- svyby(formula=fo, design=dsg, by=~county, 
                 FUN=svyciprop, vartype="ci", method="xlogit")
    names(fit)[2] <- 'mean'
    fit$sexual_orientation <- x
    fit
  }) |> do.call(what='rbind')      
}
```

then

```
get_table(df_svy_z1)
```

---

*Data:*

```
n <- 2000
set.seed(130)
sogi <- data.frame(t(rmultinom(n, 1, prob=c(.94, .03, .02, .01)))) |>
  setNames(c("straight", "gay", "bisexual", "other"))
df_sogi <- data.frame(ind=seq_len(n),
            county=as.factor(rep(LETTERS[1:10], each=n/10)),
            sexual_orientation=as.factor((0:3)[apply(sogi == 1, 1, which)]),
            pw=runif(n, 0.2, 3.5))
df_svy_z1 <- survey::svydesign(id=~ind, data=df_sogi, weights=~pw, strata=~county)
```

Comment: Thanks, @jay.sf. It works, but I don't understand some of it:  what is the "\" operator in `\(dsg)` and `\(x)`? Or "what" in `do.call(what='rbind')`? Any orientation or annotation you could provide would be really helpful, though I hesitate to ask for more than the really helpful code you've already provided.

Comment: @DavidCrow ``\`` is just shorthand for `function`, so you may also write `function(dsg)` if that's more clear to you. `do.call(what, args, ...)` allows to evaluate a function providing it's name and it's arguments as a list; since the `lapply` throws a list, we conveniently may `rbind` it this way. Note that when piping into `do.call`, using the argument name `what=` is crucial, so that the list gets piped into the next argument `args=`.

Comment: One more question, @jay.sf: in the code that creates the data for the reprex, why is the survey design object created by `survey::svydesign` assigned twice to `df_svy_z1`?

Comment: @DavidCrow Just a typo, corrected! Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1):

While you already have your answer, you could also try the `surveytable` package for cleaner output.

In the call to `tab_subset()`, I set the last argument to `c("A", "B")` to limit the output to the first two counties. Omit this argument to show all the counties.

```r
library(surveytable)
```

```r
set_survey(df_svy_z1)
#> * To adjust how counts are rounded, see ?set_count_int
#>                        _                                                                    
#> Survey name            df_svy_z1                                                            
#> Number of variables    4                                                                    
#> Number of observations 2000                                                                 
#> Info1                  Stratified Independent Sampling design (with replacement)            
#> Info2                  svydesign(id = ~ind, data = df_sogi, weights = ~pw, strata = ~county)
set_count_int()
#> * Rounding counts to the nearest integer.
#> * ?set_count_int for other options.
options(surveytable.check_present = FALSE)

tab_subset("sexual_orientation", "county", c("A", "B"))

           sexual_orientation (county = A) {df_svy_z1}           
┌───────┬────────┬────┬─────┬─────┬─────────┬─────┬──────┬──────┐
│ Level │ Number │ SE │  LL │  UL │ Percent │  SE │   LL │   UL │
├───────┼────────┼────┼─────┼─────┼─────────┼─────┼──────┼──────┤
│ 0     │    346 │ 15 │ 318 │ 377 │    91.1 │ 2.4 │ 85.2 │ 95.2 │
├───────┼────────┼────┼─────┼─────┼─────────┼─────┼──────┼──────┤
│ 1     │     14 │  6 │   4 │  48 │     3.6 │ 1.6 │  1.2 │  8.3 │
├───────┼────────┼────┼─────┼─────┼─────────┼─────┼──────┼──────┤
│ 2     │     16 │  6 │   6 │  42 │     4.2 │ 1.6 │  1.6 │  8.8 │
├───────┼────────┼────┼─────┼─────┼─────────┼─────┼──────┼──────┤
│ 3     │      4 │  3 │   0 │ Inf │     1   │ 0.9 │  0.1 │  4.6 │
└───────┴────────┴────┴─────┴─────┴─────────┴─────┴──────┴──────┘

           sexual_orientation (county = B) {df_svy_z1}           
┌───────┬────────┬────┬─────┬─────┬─────────┬─────┬──────┬──────┐
│ Level │ Number │ SE │  LL │  UL │ Percent │  SE │   LL │   UL │
├───────┼────────┼────┼─────┼─────┼─────────┼─────┼──────┼──────┤
│ 0     │    335 │ 14 │ 308 │ 364 │    92.4 │ 2.3 │ 86.4 │ 96.3 │
├───────┼────────┼────┼─────┼─────┼─────────┼─────┼──────┼──────┤
│ 1     │     13 │  6 │   3 │  54 │     3.6 │ 1.7 │  1.1 │  8.6 │
├───────┼────────┼────┼─────┼─────┼─────────┼─────┼──────┼──────┤
│ 2     │     14 │  6 │   4 │  46 │     3.9 │ 1.7 │  1.3 │  8.7 │
├───────┼────────┼────┼─────┼─────┼─────────┼─────┼──────┼──────┤
│ 3     │      1 │  1 │   0 │ Inf │     0.1 │ 0.1 │  0   │  0.8 │
└───────┴────────┴────┴─────┴─────┴─────────┴─────┴──────┴──────┘
```

<sup>Created on 2024-01-19 with [reprex v2.1.0](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Cool beans, @astra. Many thanks. Can this also be used for proportions? My main concern is confidence intervals out of bounds. How does the `survey.table` package handle confidence intervals for proportions near 0 or 1?

Comment: CI's of proportions are always between 0 and 1. The specific formula used is the 95% Korn-Graubard confidence interval (CI).

Comment: Thanks, @Alex. The reason I ask is that, to the best of my knowledge, the default method for `survey` is symmetrical, based on the t-test, and sometimes returns CIs below 0 or above 1. So, though CIs of proportions *should* be between 0 and 1, using the `survey` package and `confint` for two-way contingency tables can return out-of-bounds CIs. See the reprex here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77755536/how-can-i-get-cis-around-row-proportions-in-the-survey-package/77761033?noredirect=1#comment137092523_77761033

Comment: It looks like `surveytable` is a different package that takes a `svydesign` object for input. Is that right? Looking at your example above, I notice that in county = B, the CI is 0 for the third level of `sexual_orientation`. I'm guessing that's due to rounding?

Comment: @DavidCrow Yes, that's correct. The CI is for the percentage is between 0% and 0.8%. The KG CI that `surveytable` uses for percentages is always within bounds -- always between 0% and 100%.